# SCCM 2012 R2 Software Updates are delayed

Tags: wsus, sccm-2012-r2

I want to deploy Updates to my clients through SCCM 2012 R2. Every thing is nice but the problem is that when a new computer is joined to my network SCCM will discovery it and install the agent automatically but it does not receive the Updates; however after roughly two hours it receives the Updates completely.

I forced the agent to get Updates through going to the Control Panel-> Configuration Manager-> Running all Actions but does not work consistently.

I checked the logs file in client and it seems there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

SCCM used to be called SMS, which was lovingly nicknamed Slow Moving Software. SMS was designed to be deployed at a large scale (10s of 1000s of clients) in a geographically distributed network. This design choice means that it is implemented as [pull technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_technology) with randomized client pulling times.

When a new client is installed a number of things have to happen before it installs Software Updates: The client needs to discover the Management Point, pull Policy, run some Inventory tasks, download the Updates, install them if the advertisement deadline is elapsed and it is not in a Maintenance Window, wait for the reboot and so on. Things have to happen on the server as well, it needs to assign the newly discovered Resource Record into its various Collections (dynamic Collection membership) so it gets the SUP Deployment, run summarization on the state messages the client/s are sending back and so on.

If all this is happening in under two hours your SCCM implementation just fine! That's about as fast as Slow Moving Software is going to move. Relax, grab a cup of coffee and sit back!

If you want your freshly imaged machines to be immediately up-to-date, look at adding an Install Software Updates step into your Task Sequence or do offline updating of the .wim file periodically.

**TL;DR; SCCM is fine. It just likes to take its time.**

Answer (score 0):

I'll add that you can kick start this process by running the "Software Updates Scan Cycle" action from the Configuration Manager control panel applet.

Generally speaking though, if you are deploying a new system with SCCM your task sequence would handle the updates. Since you're adding a system outside of that approach, you'll have to either wait for the software update cycle to occur or kick it off manually.